# When will encoders for map type be available?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to explore lot in Spark 2.0, so i'm curious to know "When will encoders for map type be available ?"

Thanks for your suggestion in advance. 
Vinoth.

Comment: This doesn't pertain to a programming problem. You probably won't get any better answer here than you would on Google.

Answer (score -1):

For primitive types and case classes there are available since 1.6 like:

```
implicit val enc: Encoder[Map[String, Int]] = ExpressionEncoder()
```

For any other objects just use Kryo:

```
implicit val enc = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Map[Any, Any]]
```

Comment: These don't seem to work on Map.